# adding Strings (names) to separate instances

Tags: java

So I have a class called `Person` and want to create 3 instances to hold names.

```
Person p1 = new Person();    
Person p2 = new Person();     
Person p3 = new Person();
```

I want to add at least 2 names into each instance but wanted to know if I was doing it the correct way.

```
p1. addName("John"); 
p1. addName("James");

p2. addName("Mike"); 
p2. addName("Laila");

p3. addName("Steven");   
p3. addName("Ryan");
```

By coding it this way would the names for each instances always overwrite the first name?

or would i need to code it as `p1. addName("John" + "James");`?

Comment: It entirely depends on how you implemented `Person`.

Comment: Where is the code for your `Person` class?

Comment: If your addName method filling array,it is okay,if just assigns the String,it will overwrite and you will lose the previous assignments.

Comment: Why not "John James"? :-)

Comment: Where is your `Person` class code ? 
Anyway assuming you have one variable called `name` in your `Person` class and a method called `addName(String name) { this.name = name; }` then in this case you have to pass the full name in one method call otherwise they override each other, but if you need to store a first and last name for each then better to have two variables one for each and two method one to set the value for each

Answer (score 0):

Beside my above comment here is the way to do it, let me explain more, your class can either have one variable called name and in this case you need to have one method to set the name as the one you called addName, i just called it setName, it is naming convention since it sets the name of the instance variable, and in this case you have to pass the full name as one string including both first and last names otherwise they will overwrite each other. The second option is to have to instance variables one for the first name and one for the last name and have two method to set each. You do this if you need to store each of the first name and last name separately (which is better in my opinion but it depends)

option 1:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

---

```
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.setName("Jhon James");
```

or

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName= firstName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName= lastName;
    }
}
```

---

```
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.setFirstName("Jhon");
p1.setLastName("James");
```